# Charactor Length Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to control an element's character length from another element using javascript. It should not allow to insert a char in middle of character?

Comment: Do you mean "string" length? "char" and "character" are the same thing. You can't insert a char into a character.

Comment: A character doesn't really have a length. Do you mean string length?

Comment: i have 2 text boxes in my page.For first one only 200 characters are allowed but i cant write the any events for that field as i don have the permission. What i should do to control this?

Comment: @Krow yes String length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the maxlength attribute:

You can also extend this using JavaScript

http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html